# How to design a singleton class in C++ on Linux using boost::call_once?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, boost, singleton

I am designing a thread-safe singleton class in C++ on Linux using `boost::call_once`.

I got the following compiler error:

```
/tmp/ccLanvZI.o: In function `SingleTon::getInstance()':
singleTon.cpp:(.text._ZN9SingleTon11getInstanceEv[SingleTon::getInstance()]+0x1b): undefined reference to `SingleTon::p'
/tmp/ccLanvZI.o: In function `SingleTon::makeInstance()':
singleTon.cpp:(.text._ZN9SingleTon12makeInstanceEv[SingleTon::makeInstance()]+0x21): undefined reference to `SingleTon::SingleTon()'
singleTon.cpp:(.text._ZN9SingleTon12makeInstanceEv[SingleTon::makeInstance()]+0x2c): undefined reference to `SingleTon::p'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [singlton] Error 1
```

After seeing some posts, I still do not know how to handle this error.
How do I change the `void (SingleTon::)()` to `void (*)()`?

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/once.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/threadpool.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>

boost::once_flag flag = BOOST_ONCE_INIT;

class SingleTon
{
    private:
        static SingleTon *p;
        SingleTon();
        SingleTon(const SingleTon&);
        SingleTon& operator=(const SingleTon&);
        void makeInstance();

    public:
        SingleTon* getInstance();

        ~SingleTon()
        {
            if (p)
                delete p;
        }  
};

void SingleTon::makeInstance() 
{
    p = new SingleTon;
    return;
}

SingleTon* SingleTon::getInstance()
{
    boost::call_once( makeInstance  , flag); // error !!!
    return p;
}


int main()
{
    SingleTon *s;
    s = SingleTon::getInstance();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can't resist: the title has the answer. You made the "Error of designing a Singleton class".

Comment: @sehe: What, you can't resist the truth?

Comment: You missed a space … it’s “single ton” ;-)

Comment: "I am designing a thread-safe singleTon class in C++" -- err, good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error indicates boost::call_once doesn't work on member function pointers. This is because you forgot to make both makeInstance and getInstance static.

Comment: I have updated the code and still have errors for adding some code to do test in main(), any help is apprciated. thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Why have you written a destructor? Which instance do you plan to destroy?  Oh wait, there's only one, cos it's a singleton, so in that case why does the destructor try to delete the instance? Infinitely recursive failure.

Singletons smell anyway, avoid them.

Comment: Damn - wish I'd spotted that :)  +1 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As AardvarkSoup (tasty *and* nutritious) pointed out, you need `makeInstance()` and `getInstance()` to be static.

Also, you need to define `SingleTon()`, not just declare it, since it's used in `makeInstance()`.

Finally, you need to initialise the static member `p`, like:

```
SingleTon* SingleTon::p(nullptr);
```

This makes the code compile.  However, designing a thread-safe singleton class is non-trivial.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern) for piles of links to very full explanations as to why you should try and avoid using singletons.